# Creating a model with array members

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model

I want to make a model to add things to a database. An example [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html) uses this class:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

But  what would I do if I wanted some members to be arrays? Like if I wanted an array of genres instead of one. 
I know this is wrong but Im too new to C# to see why or to know how to do it correctly:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string[] Genres { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would reccomend to use List instead of an array

Answer (score 0):

You could simply declare the property as some type of collection such an `IEnumerable<string>` or `List<string>` as seen below :

```
public class Movie
{
    // Other properties omitted for brevity
    public IEnumerable<string> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

And then when you actually populate it, you could use a concrete implementation like a `List<string>` or `string[]`.